# Extract argumens values from the format string

Tags: c#, regex, format

I have a string which is actually a format for example `"m_{0}A1_{1}Tmp"`
given such format string and data I need to extract the values of the arguments i.e. `{0}` and `{1}`
Following the example above if the data is `m_TomerA1_DbTmp` , I should extract that the first argument is `Tomer` and the second is `Db`
Will be glad to hear how can I do it?
My intuition says that I need regular expression here...

Comment: Yes you may use RegEx but I'd also try to do it with plain IndexOf("A1_") because prologue and epilogue are fixed and doesn't need to be matched. Here expression is even too much _regular_...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti-it is only the example - the format string can be any

Comment: Are there **rules**? Even with regex format string may vary but you have to define **how**.

Comment: @AdrianoRepettiit is an input

Comment: What you want might be ambiguous, even if it is required that both {0} and {1} must be non-empty.  What should {0} and {1} be in the following string: `"m_someA1_A1_thingTmp"`? {0} = `"some"` and {1} =`"A1_thing"`? Or, {0} = `"someA1_"` and {1} = `"thing"`? Both cases would be a valid result. If your code can possibly deal with strings similar to my example, then you will have to make a decision whether you want to have {0} being greedier than {1} or vice versa...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex and retrieve the Group 1 and Group 2 matches:

```
m_(.*?)A1_(.*?)Tmp
```

On the demo, look at the captured groups on the right.

In C#:

```
var myRegex = new Regex("m_(.*?)A1_(.*?)Tmp");
Match theMatch = myRegex.Match(yourString);
String token1 = theMatch.Groups[1].Value;
String token2 = theMatch.Groups[2].Value;
```

**Explanation**

- `m_` matches literal characters
- `(.*?)` captures to Group 1 and lazily matches everything up to...
- `A1_` literal
- `(.*?)` captures to Group 2 and lazily matches everything up to...
- `Tmp` literal
- the Group i is retrieved with `theMatch.Groups[i].Value`